# MPX2100DP differential pressure sensor with Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, sensor, differential-amplifier, air-pressure

I am trying to use a pressure sensor which is MPX2100DP. Datasheet is; https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPX2100.pdf

My goal is to measure the air pressure inside a pipe. First of all, I tried it alone. 1st = GND, 2nd = A1, 3rd = +12V. (I connected GND to power supply and arduino.) Whether I close the pipe or not, the result is 1023.. Also, I tried plug the hose into the other port. There arent any difference. Then, I tried to use a differential amplifier to compare the normal air with the air in the pipe and increase the value, but the values ​​​​reflected unchanged at the opamp output. I used the instrumentation amplifier AD620AN, thinking that it is lost because of the low signal, but I still could not get any results. Where is my fault? Someone could advice me? I will convert voltage to pressure but firstly ı want to solve the problem of value.

[image]

Arduino code is ;

```
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
 float sensorValue = analogRead(A1);
 Serial.print("A/D is:    ");
 Serial.println(sensorValue);
 delay(750);
}
```

With AD620AN;
[image]

Comment: Please, post a proper schematic. If you don't have a schematic in some CAD program, you can even draw it in paint (try to make it readable). Also, how many volts do you actually have on chip output? Measure with multimeter please.

Comment: The ADC result of 1023 indicates that you are reading a very high voltage. Try measuring the sensor output voltage with a multimeter first.

Comment: How did you connect the AD620? Power supplies?

Comment: I hope my drawing was self explanatory. I connected the output directly to the arduino and got 1023, that is 5V, as an analog value. I will measure with a multimeter and reply again,thank you.

Comment: I added a new drawing circuit with the AD620AN. I was using +12V power supply. I used 330 ohm and my gain was 150, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Don't forget a decoupling capacitor of 0.1uF-1uF, as nearest as possible, between pins supply of AD620 ...

Comment: Hi sir, i measured the sensor output voltage with a multimeter. Only when there is no self pipe the result is ±Vout=6.07 V. When I close the pipe +Vout=6.08V, -Vout=6.06V.

Comment: NB: Have you seen that "differential" is only ... 40 mV max ? Reduce the gain at 50, and set a level reference of about 2.5 V.

Comment: Should i do it when using the AD620AN? actually I saw 40 mV but I did it because the supply voltage is 10-16V. But now I'm trying your advice.

Comment: sorry sir, how did you calculate it? for example ı want to set the reference voltage as 3.3V how can ı calculate the gain? ı know that normally gain is calculating from (49,4k/R) +1.
And why am ı not the getting correct values when ı just use only mpx2100dp.

Comment: The gain don't change with common-mode voltage. But, if the gain is too high, output voltage can be higher than ADC full range of Arduino board... See the last picture in answer.

Comment: As pressure can be higher or lower (relatively), the differential "voltage" can be positive or negative, then you have to set a Vr reference. I choose 2.5 V to be at the mid-level of Arduino full scale.

Comment: See also this post for information https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/581532/read-three-signals-from-mpx2102dp-pressure-sensor?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the AD620 correctly?
Note that "common-mode" voltage is eliminated for output.

Here is [image]what you should get ...

Be careful if Gain and Vref are not well chosen.
The output voltage will be higher than ADC Arduino full range.
**Don't forget decoupling capacitor of AD620, nearest supply pins.**

[image]

Comment: Oh, I think ı used the AD620AN wrong.. Ok, ı will search your reply thank you sir.

Comment: I edited my circuit. i designed a voltage reducer for vref=2.5V and the gain is 50 with 1k ohms. My results are:  Vout is 3.1V on the multimeter. While the value is 616 on the arduino when the hose is open, the value is 400 when i turn it off. i think these are the correct values. Now i am going to convert the voltage to pressure, thank you for your reply and helps. My circuit diagram is; [link](https://resimyukle.io/r/oga6zwRJl7)

Comment: is the link i just added?

Comment: Yes. Norton gives a warning in red... No worries, make an answer at your own question and add the picture ...

Answer (score 0):

This is my last circuit and i get correct values. (batteries represent power supply.)

Note: Actually I didn't understand where I should place the decoupling capacitors. I tried to put it on pin 2 and pin 3 of AD620AN but got the same values.

[image]

And it's my arduino code. There is a conversion of voltage to pressure.

```
int offset =0; 
int pressure; 

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int Value = 0;
  float  Vout = analogRead(A1);
  Value = Value + analogRead(A1);

 
  float Voltage = Vout /1023 *5;
  pressure = ( (Vout - offset) / 0.0004 ) / pow(10,3) ; 

 
  Serial.print("Vout: ");
  Serial.print(Vout);
 
  Serial.print("     Voltage: ");
  Serial.print(Voltage);
 
  Serial.print("     Pressure " );
  Serial.print(pressure,1);
  Serial.println(" kPa");
  delay(750);
}




//When hose is open; Vout: 620.00     Voltage: 3.03     Pressure 1550 kPa
//When hose is closed; Vout: 420.00     Voltage: 2.05     Pressure 1050 kPa
```

Comment: Decoupling is a precaution against some noise generated by supplies and characteristics of sensible opamps are "stabilized" ... Much less trouble.

Comment: ok sir ı got it, thanks again..